# Upgrade from iPhone 3G 4.2.1 to iPhone 5S 7.0.4

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, backup, restore

A friend of mine has a good old iPhone 3G (yep, the thing still works :)) and he just bought an iPhone 5S. When he takes a backup of the iPhone 3G in iTunes (iCloud isn't supported in iOS 4) and tries a restore on his iPhone 5S, the restore completely fails...

No errors are given. The iPhone 5S just starts in his configuration screen (select language). So it looks like the backup cannot be restored.
Weird thing is, when he tries to turn off the iPhone 5S, the background screen of his iPhone 3G is shown... So some data has been transferred, but not enough for the iPhone 5S to boot with the restore...

What's going on here? Is the backup of the iPhone 3G too old? Or is he missing something?

Answer (score -1):

I just upgraded from 3G to 5S and at first had the same problem. What I learned in another chat was that prior to restore I had to update to IOS 6.1... Once the OS was updated, I backed up the 3G and did a restore to the 5S from the latest 3G backup. It took a long time, but was well worth it.

Comment: How did you update your iPhone 3G to iOS 6.1? Are you referring to an iPhone 3Gs?

Comment: iPhone 3G doesn't support iOS6 if I'm not mistaken...